# Group Conv in TensorFlow 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2

Does TensorFlow2.x support Group Convolution?
I have seen a lot of posts/blogs/tutorials saying that TensorFlow does not support it, and I have also seen some posts saying that tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D is equivalent to group convolution. However, I noticed that there is a group parameter in tf.keras.layers.Conv2d, is this the group convolution described in many papers (for example, ResNeXt paper)? Or am I misunderstanding it?
Any help and explanation would be great!

edit: an example of group conv (the third one) and equivalent parrellel conv (first two). Example from ResNeXt paper
[image: group conv]

a group conv of 32 groups with depth 4 in pytorch, which means total output channel is 128:
torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3,3), groups=32)

more specifically, a group conv of n groups and depth of d with input channel i will split i input channels into n groups of equal size, each group will be a normal convolution with the same kernel size, stride that has i/n channels as input, and d channels as output. The output of all groups will be concatenated into n*d channels and passed to the next layer as input.

Comment: Can you describe more in detail what a Group Convolution is? Maybe use a toy input example and its expected output. Although I believe to have the answer to your question, I don´t feel confident answering it due to its vagueness.

Comment: @ibarrond sorry I can't come up with a specific example, but I just updated my question showing an image of it and a corresponding code in Pytorch. It is basically having several convolutional layers in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, tensorflow does support the Group Conv directly with the `groups` argument. From [`Conv2D arguments`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#arguments) in the official docs of TF2:

> *groups*: A positive integer specifying the number of groups in which the input is split along the channel axis. Each group is convolved separately with filters / groups filters. The output is the concatenation of all the groups results along the channel axis. Input channels and filters must both be divisible by groups.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I thought at the beginning, but since almost every posts/tutorials said TensorFlow does not support it, and many of them were written in the past 6 months, it just worried me so much. I guess they just copied their tutorials from outdated articles.

Answer (score 1):

**Tensorflow 2 definitely does NOT support grouped convolution!**

While the Doc claims that it is  supported by tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, as the 'groups' argument, when you try it you get the oft-reported error:

**“UnimplementedError:  Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.”**

This error has been repeatedly reported since 2019.

The special case of Depthwise Convolution, where the number of groups equals the number of channels, is separately supported in tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D.